# genymotion + virtualbox error

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I have an issue similar to this one, with different vbox error: Genymotion VirtualBox error, only that solutions provided there don't seem to help :/

I have installed Genymotion and VirtualBox on my computer, and set up a Samsung Galaxy S6 device through Genymotion. However, when I try to start the device, Genymotion gives me this error:

Unable to start the virtual device

VirtualBox cannot start the virtual device

To find out the cause the problem, start the virtual device from VirtualBox.

For more information, check the log files. Please refer to:www.genymotion.com/faq/logs

I try to start the device in VirtualBox, and get this error: Virtualbox Error

Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Samsung Galaxy S6 - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1440x2560

▼ Details

The virtual machine 'Google Nexus 5X - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1080x1920' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1). More details may be available in 'C:\Users\Kozzel\Desktop\aa\Google Nexus 5X - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1080x1920\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'."

I should mention that when I open VBox a window pops up and says "One or more disk image files are not currently accessible. As a result, you will not be able to operate virtual machines that use these files until they become accessible later. Press Check to open the Virtual Media Manager window and see which files are inaccessible, or press Ignore to ignore this message.